# using multiple variables in a function OR for loop in R

Tags: r

I've been unable to find the answer I need on prior posts so I am starting a new question. I am attempting to feed multiple variables into a for loop or function, to get a single output for each step through the variables. I don't need all permutations of the variables, i just need the loop or function to act one time on each element of the vectors in parallel (in the same order). Here is what I have done...

```
a=c("BP GOterms","CC GOterms","MF GOterms")
i = c(0,2,4)
j = c(2,4,6)
n = rep(n,3)

func<-function(a,i,j,n) {
  temp<-arrange(df[df$ID %in% hit[(i*n+1):(n*j)],], -Cluster,Count)
  temp$Description<-factor(temp$Description,levels=unique(temp$Description,fromLast=T))
  plot<-ggplot(temp,aes(Cluster,Description,size=Count,color=p.adjust))+geom_point()+ggtitle(a)
  print(plot)
}

mapply(func,i=i,j=j,n=n,a=a)
```

This gave me the right output 3 times over, I just want it one time

Alternatively, I have been trying something like this...

```
for (i in c(0,2,4) & j in c(2,4,6) & title in c("BP GOterms","CC GOterms","MF GOterms")) {
  temp<-arrange(df[df$ID %in% hit[(i*n+1):(n*j)],], -Cluster,Count)
  temp$Description<-factor(temp$Description,levels=unique(temp$Description,fromLast=T))
  plot<-ggplot(temp,aes(Cluster,Description,size=Count,color=p.adjust))+geom_point()+ggtitle(title)
  print(plot)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In (i * n + 1):(n * j) :
  numerical expression has 81 elements: only the first used
2: In (i * n + 1):(n * j) :
  numerical expression has 81 elements: only the first used
3: In Ops.factor(Cluster) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

To run my code you would need the df, which is quite large. But here is an example of what it looks like....

```
structure(list(Cluster = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M1", 
"M2"), class = "factor"), ONTOLOGY = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BP", "CC", "MF"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = c("GO:1901673", "GO:0034314", "GO:0006892", "GO:0036503", 
    "GO:0035967", "GO:0006986"), Description = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("regulation of mitotic spindle assembly", 
    "Arp2/3 complex-mediated actin nucleation", "post-Golgi vesicle-mediated transport", 
    "membrane fusion", "establishment of protein localization to membrane", 
    "ERAD pathway", "cellular response to topologically incorrect protein", 
    "response to unfolded protein", "vacuolar transport", "response to topologically incorrect protein", 
    "cytosolic transport", "endosomal transport", "vacuole organization", 
    "DNA-dependent DNA replication", "macroautophagy", "response to endoplasmic reticulum stress", 
    "Golgi vesicle transport", "rRNA processing", "myeloid leukocyte activation", 
    "rRNA metabolic process", "mitotic nuclear division", "DNA replication", 
    "regulation of mitotic cell cycle phase transition", "regulation of cell cycle phase transition", 
    "ribosome biogenesis", "proteasome-mediated ubiquitin-dependent protein catabolic process", 
    "chromosome segregation", "regulation of chromosome organization", 
    "autophagy", "process utilizing autophagic mechanism", "proteasomal protein catabolic process", 
    "ncRNA processing", "mitotic cell cycle phase transition", 
    "cell cycle phase transition", "regulation of DNA metabolic process", 
    "negative regulation of cell cycle", "ribonucleoprotein complex biogenesis", 
    "DNA repair", "ncRNA metabolic process", "regulation of mitotic cell cycle"
    ), class = "factor"), GeneRatio = c("8/1090", "10/1090", 
    "18/1090", "18/1090", "20/1090", "21/1090"), BgRatio = c("21/19527", 
    "32/19527", "95/19527", "95/19527", "97/19527", "104/19527"
    ), pvalue = c(9.7302693101372e-06, 5.88348341881873e-06, 
    4.47976958483539e-06, 4.47976958483539e-06, 3.24568370146555e-07, 
    2.40596847523017e-07), p.adjust = c(0.00248177711775767, 
    0.00171451628569576, 0.0014795185682183, 0.0014795185682183, 
    0.000229701672243719, 0.000198652797104838), qvalue = c(0.00230759974232573, 
    0.00159418720995361, 0.00137568222478875, 0.00137568222478875, 
    0.000213580629738545, 0.000184710842940477), Count = c(8L, 
    10L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 21L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: `for (i_ in 1:3) func(a[i_],i[i_],j[i_],n[i_])`

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I should have considered looping over the function. Thanks

Comment: What is `hit` ? The function returns an error `object 'hit' not found`.

Comment: I only gave a sample of what `df` looks like. You would need the full data frame for the `hit` object to be generated.  'hit' is a vector of the GOterms `df$ID` that I want to plot, and I use it to subset `df` before creating the ggplot. The `df` object is really large, so I didn't post the entire thing.